# TF 2 - Keras - Merging two seperately trained models to a new ensemble model

Tags: artificial-intelligence, python-3.7, tf.keras

Newbie here ;)

I need your help ;)

I have following problem:

I want to merge two TF 2.0 - Keras Models into a new Model.

Expect for example a ResNet50V2 without the head, and retrained on new data  - saved weights are provided and loaded:

```
    resnet50v2 = ResNet50V2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    #model.summary()
    last_layer = resnet50v2.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(last_layer)
    x = Dense(768, activation='relu', name='img_dense_768')(x)
    out = Dense(NUM_CLASS, activation='softmax', name='img_output_layer')(x)
    resnet50v2 = Model(inputs=resnet50v2.input, outputs=out)
    resnet50v2.load_weights(pathToImageModel)
```

Expect for example a Bert Network retrained on new data - saved weights are provided, in the same way as shown before.

Now I want to skip the last softmax layer from the two models and "merge" them into a new Model.

So I took the layer before the last layer, which names I know:

```
    model_image_output = model_image.get_layer('img_dense_768').output
    model_bert_output = model_bert.get_layer('bert_output_layer_768').output
```

I built two new models with these informations:

```
    model_img = Model(model_image.inputs, model_image_output)    
    model_bert = Model(model_bert.inputs, model_bert_output)
```

So now I want to concatenate the outputs of the two models into a new one and add a new "head"

```
    concatenate = Concatenate()([model_img.output,model_bert.output])
    x = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(concatenate)
    x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
    output = Dense(NUM_CLASS, activation='softmax', name='final_multimodal_output')(x)
    model_concat = Model([model_image.input, model_bert.input])
```

So far so good, model code seemed to be valid but then my knowledge ends.

The main questions are:

Also if the last softmax layers are skipped, the loaded weights should be still available or ?
The new concatened model wants to be build, ok but this ends in this error message, which I only partially understand:

> NotImplementedError: When subclassing the `Model` class, you should implement a `call` method.

Is there another way to create for example the whole ensemble network and load only the pretrained parts of it and leave the rest beeing trainable?

Am I missing something? I never did subclassing the model class? If so, it was not intended XD

May I ask kindly for some hints ?

Thanks in advance!!

Kind regards ragitagha

---

UPDATE:
So to find my mistake more quickly and provide the solution in a more precise way:

I had to change the lines

```
    concatenate = Concatenate()([model_img.output,model_bert.output])
    x = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(concatenate)
    x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
    output = Dense(NUM_CLASS, activation='softmax', name='final_multimodal_output')(x)
    model_concat = Model([model_image.input, model_bert.input])
```

to:

```
    concatenate = Concatenate()([model_img.output,model_bert.output])
    x = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(concatenate)
    x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
    output = Dense(NUM_CLASS, activation='softmax', name='final_multimodal_output')(x)
    model_concat = Model([model_image.input, model_bert.input], output)
```

Comment: in model_concat... it seems you miss the output layer: Model([model_image.input, model_bert.input], output)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani - Thanks for this valuable hint, it seems that 11 p.m. should not be my favorite time of working! XD It is working! Thanks a lot !